# 2012 Mercedes c250

Tags: noise, mercedes-benz

Hello I have a Mercedes c250 2012 and I am currently hearing ticking noises I’m not to sure where it’s coming from but when I put my window down you can hear it and I can only hear it when I accelerate and noise gets louder when I increase speed

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you expound on your situation? Can you tell if the noise gets louder with engine speed or vehicle speed (changing gears doesn't change the noises pitch)?

Answer (score 1):

A ticking you can hear coming from outside, that increases in volume and *frequency* when you accelerate is likely to be something stuck in a tire ticking as it impacts the road surface. So I'd check all 4 tires first. If you can have someone else listen out of the windows, you may be able to identify which corner of the car it is coming from, which will narrow things down considerably.

If it's not the tire, take the wheel off and look at the brake and behind. Is there damage to a drive shaft, driveshaft boot or CV boot that could make a tick each rotation?